# Unity. Вызов функции из другого скрипта

Tags: c#, unity3d, touch

Помогите дописать код
Нужно чтобы при таче по кнопке выполнялась функция (func1) из другого скрипта (anotherScript).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Button: MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnMouseDown() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Button: MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject TargetObj; //не забудь перетащить в инспекторе сюда нужный обьект
    private SomeMonoBehavior _actionTarget; //замени SomeMonoBehavior  на название скрипта

    public void Start()
    {
        _actionTarget = TargetObj.GetComponent<SomeMonoBehavior>();
    }

    private void OnMouseDown() {
        _actionTarget.Method();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public anotherScript anotherS;

public class Button: MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnMouseDown() {
    anotherS = GetComponent<anotherScript>();

    anotherS.func1();

    //Обязательно в другом скрипте у func1() должен быть модификатор доступа 
    //public

    //Перетаскиваешь другой скрипт на объект и добавляешь его в появившееся 
    //поле anotherS у основного

    }
}
```